# How can I respawn the Ender Dragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a server and the Ender dragon has been defeated.  However, returning to The End does not respawn the Ender Dragon.  How can I get the final boss back on a vanilla server without using mods?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Minecraft 1.9 and higher

To respawn the Ender Dragon, you must craft 4 [End Crystals](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_crystal#Crafting):

[image: End Crystal crafting recipe]

Place them around the End portal like so:

[image: End crystal placement]

A respawning sequence will begin, refreshing the obsidian towers and original ender crystals, and then the dragon is spawned above the portal.

Answer (score 16):

#### Minecraft 1.8 and lower

Most servers I've seen just reset the whole dimension by deleting the `DIM1` (vanilla) or `world_the_end` (CraftBukkit) folder.

There is another way to respawn the Ender dragon, that will keep the player builds in The End, but it is a bit more complicated:
You need an NBT editor (like [NBT Explorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/)). You need to open `DIM1\r.0.0.mca` and edit in `Chunk [0, 0]` the `TerrainPopulated` property to `0`:

[image: NBT Explorer screenshot]

When the chunk is loaded again, the dragon will be re-created. Note that this will also re-create the obsidian tower(s) in that (0, 0) chunk. Also note that when you kill the new dragon, a new exit portal with a new dragon egg will be created – you may want to switch to creative to remove the unnecessary ones.

---

*From version 1.9, the Ender dragon can be summoned in-game by [placing four Ender Crystals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/241663/28182) on the edges of the exit portal pool, one on each side. More details on the [Minecraft Wiki - Ender Dragon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon#Respawning)*

Answer (score 2):

#### Use WorldEdit

It can be done from in game with the WorldEdit plugin (which most servers do), without needing to delete the `-dim 1` folder, and therefore preserving any structure you built away from the main platform in the End.

It's rather easy:

1. Go through the end portal.
2. `//wand`
3. Left click on one corner of the end platform
4. Go to opposite corner (at least 200m away) and make a pile of blocks roughly 20 high
5. Right click top block on your pile
6. `//regen`

And poof, everything in that entire area is as it original was. Hurry and `/spawn` before the dragon can generate and it wont even be there until a new player comes through the portal.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use Commands

The following command will summon an Ender Dragon:

```
/summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Use Enderspawn

In vanilla Minecraft, spawning in an Ender Dragon Egg won't work:

> You can get a plain white spawn egg that reads Spawn Ender Dragon by typing **/give [player] 383 1 63**, which is the item ID. However, when you try to spawn it, you cannot and it does not really work as anything.
> *taken from the wiki: [Minecraft Wiki Enderdragon](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/enderspawn/)*

Instead, you can use [EnderSpawn](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon) - a server plugin that allows you to easily respawn the Ender Dragon, without having to regenerate the End and lose any player constructions.