# Respawn the original ender dragon on server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

On my server, we've lost the dragon egg so are trying to get it back using as little cheating as possible. Because of that, we're now looking in to ways to reset the dragon counter and make the original dragon appear again. We've had no luck so far though, so I was wondering whether someone here could help. The other post on the matter: [Respawn the Ender Dragon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127252/respawn-the-ender-dragon) has been of no use.

So we're looking to do the following on a server:

- Summon an ender dragon
- Have this dragon drop an egg without changing loot tables (NBT editing is fine though)
- Keep the end intact

Having it drop the original 12k xp is fine.

Ideally, we'd do this using a command from the console, but other methods are acceptable. Hope you can help!

Comment: If you have access to the server files I think if you delete the world_the_end folder it should regenerate the end again with a new dragon. Using multiverse core on my server any time I create a new "End" world it always has one in it already.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it's pretty clear that you didn't actually read my post, seeing as one of my points was that it had to _"keep the end intact"_.

Comment: Oh, must have missed that. No need to sound like a dick about it though.

Comment: No problem. Apologies ^^

Comment: I was about to post an answer, but it only explained how to Respawn The Ender Dragon, and not the Original. Do you want me to still post it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with commands, but if you have access to the server files you do it with a little bit of NBT editing (with e.g. [NBT Explorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/)):

1. First you need to break all portal blocks - both in the the exit portal and on all end gateways on the main island. You can do this in creative. Unfortunately there is no way around that - if there is a single portal entity within 128 blocks from the center, the game will know you have already beaten the dragon.
2. (optional) If you want to have the fight with the end crystals healing the dragon, respawn the dragon manually and wait for the spawn sequence to complete and then leave the game. If you don't care, just skip this step.
3. Then, (stop the server) with the NBT editor delete `level.dat/Data/DimensionData/1/DragonFight` (save and re-start the server):

[image: delete DragonFight NBT]

Then, as soon as one enters The End the dragon will appear and the game will consider it to be the original dragon. When it is killed, the game will put a dragon egg on the portal. Also the dragon will drop the XP of the first kill (12000).

Comment: I tried this in single player but it didn't work. Thus, I moved to removing the lavel.dat.old file, deleting the dragonfight entries and changing the population values of the center 4 chunks to 0. Even under those circumstances it didn't work.

Comment: @MitchellFaas There is one more step which I didn't know it was needed -  no portal entities on the main island. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the fatest way to repair the ender dragon I found is deleting DIM1 dimension (warning: it's deleting all the ender), and after open your world with NBTExplorer like the picture above and go in level.dat/Data/DimensionData/1/DragonFight and delete the all folder of DragonFight. It will reset all your end normally (I think).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

(these commands must be run from client, to do this, op yourself by typing "op [username]" in the console)

if you already beat it just type

```
/give @p dragon_egg
```

if not, you can just re-spawn the dragon the old fashioned way ^_^

```
/summon minecraft:ender_dragon
```

Comment: They seem to be looking for a way to do this via the server though, and not in game.

Comment: This works, of course. But we really do want to respawn the original dragon as opposed to just spawning in items.

Comment: that's why i added the /summon command :)